# How to deal with ActiveLow Reset / change implicit clock frequency?

Tags: scala, fpga, chisel

1. How to config implicit clock from 100MHz to 50 MHz(So its show up in my WaveGTK Sim)?
2. How to deal with Active Low / Active High?
   ex.

```
val io = IO(new Bundle() {
val activeLowReset = Input(Bool()).toActiveLow() 
//??? Did chisel have something like this.
})
```

turn out my Board is ActiveLow Reset, it always reset.

3. Any example to use Scala/trait with chisel? or Cats?

After 2 week of trying to deploy chisel on real FPGA?
Here all my question.

Answer (score 2):

> How to config implicit clock from 100MHz to 50 MHz(So its show up in my WaveGTK Sim)?

If you are using [chiseltest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest) than that won't be possible. You can generate Verilog from Chisel and then write your own testbench in Verilog or C++ (for Verilator) which will give you the freedom to define your own [timescale](https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-timescale).

> How to deal with Active Low / Active High? ex.

You should be able to just invert the reset. Like this:

```scala
class ToplevelWrapper extends Module {
  // same I/O as our "Example" toplevel
  val io = IO(new ToplevelIO)
  // create an inverted reset signal
  val invertedReset = ~reset.asBool
  // you can write the following if you want a async reset
  // val invertedReset = (~reset.asBool).asAsyncReset
  // instantiate our "Example" toplevel with the inverted reset
  val top = withReset(invertedReset) {
    Module(new Example)
  }
  // hook up I/Os
  io <> top.io
}
```

[Full example on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lmr5H0YHTreV9qzw9WzczA)

> Any example to use Scala/trait with chisel? or Cats?

Generally I would recommend not to rely too much on traits or advance functional programming since most other hardware developers will otherwise struggle using and understanding your code.
There was an interesting use of type classes in the past for the [dsptools library](https://github.com/ucb-bar/dsptools)